# How to run command in terminal Intellij SDK

Tags: intellij-plugin

I would like to create the RunConfiguration which will run command in intergrated terminal and its provides. By the word “provider” I mean powershell.exe or cmd.exe. I found how to run the command line using GlobalCommandLine or PtyCommandLine, but it's creates the process when I want to run command using cmd.exe or powershell.exe provider. I found new answer with strange class ShTerminalRunner, but it uses ShellTerminalWidget which located in org.jetbrains.plugins.terminal package and I got access there by adding "terminal" to plugins in build.gradle.kts file:

```kotlin
plugins.set(listOf(
    "terminal"
))
```

But after running I'm getting an error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jetbrains/plugins/terminal/TerminalToolWindowManager
    at code.sh.ShTerminalRunner.run(ShTerminalRunner.kt:29)
    at code.sh.runconfig.FlowRunConfiguration$getState$1.startProcess(FlowRunConfiguration.kt:29)
    at com.intellij.execution.configurations.CommandLineState.execute(CommandLineState.java:61)
    at com.intellij.execution.runners.DefaultRunProgramRunner$execute$1.invoke(DefaultRunProgramRunner.kt:29)
    at ... stack trace
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jetbrains.plugins.terminal.TerminalToolWindowManager PluginClassLoader(plugin=PluginDescriptor(name=Pon, id=code.sh, descriptorPath=plugin.xml, path=~\Documents\IdeaProjects\Pon\build\idea-sandbox\plugins\Pon, version=1.0-SNAPSHOT, package=null, isBundled=false), packagePrefix=null, state=active)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.kt:156)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
    ... 46 more
```

Edit: My code is copy paste from https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/plugins/sh/terminal/src/com/intellij/sh/run/terminal/ShTerminalRunner.java

Answer (score 0):

As usual, my mistake was due to inattention. I just forgot to add the  tag to plugin.xml, [I understand it from here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/plugin-dependencies.html#3-dependency-declaration-in-pluginxml)

After adding this tag:

```
<depends>org.jetbrains.plugins.terminal</depends>
```

My problem is solved:
[image of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RW5jq.png)